# Cant request root on android

Tags: android

Im trying to require root access in my app but the background thread gets stuck in the waitFor();
What am i doing wrong?

```
        try {
            Log.i("DEBUG", "start");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su").waitFor();
            Log.i("DEBUG", "yay");

            ..........
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: is your mobile rooted?

Comment: yes. rooted and super user showed up asking if i should grant it, i selected "allow" and checked that it should remember my choice.

Comment: Try using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su \n").waitFor();`

Comment: I agree with @RaghavSood Yeah. It Won't execute the command until you press the enter ( \n here ).. That is a tricky part in android console programming :))

Comment: @RaghavSood now it wont even toast "myApp has been granted etc"

Comment: @RaghavSood nevermind, i removed it from the rememebred choices and the prompt appears, but still no "yay" is logged...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this code I wrote for my own software. It works well.

```
Process p;    
try {
        // Try to execute SU
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "/system/bin/sh"});
        DataOutputStream stdin = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
        // User has responded.. Let's see whats the response.
        // Execute ID to see if we are root
        stdin.writeBytes("id\n");
        DataInputStream stdout = new DataInputStream(p.getInputStream());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int read = 0;
        String out = new String();
        // Read the output
        while(true){
            read = stdout.read(buffer);
            out += new String(buffer, 0, read);
            if(read<4096) break;
        }
        // Check output
        if(!out.contains("root")){
            // User denied the root prompt
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed To Get Root! Are You Rooted!?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Use granted... Do what you want here. Or set a flag that indicates we are now root
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: works! Still i have no idea why my thread was stuck at waitFor(); tho im happy it finally works! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @AdnanElezovic. I had forgot to define the Process p. I edited the code to be right. I think you've figured it out. I edited it for others to use  :)